# converting Linq/Lambda expressions to anonymous methods

Tags: .net, linq, lambda, anonymous-methods

I usually get code samples that uses lambda expressions. I am stil using .net 2.0, and find it difficult to work with such code, for example

```
foreach(var item in items)
{
    var catCopy = item;
    foreach(var word in words)
    {
        var wordCopy = word;
        var waitCallback = new WaitCallback(state =>
        {
            DoSomething(wordCopy, catCopy);
        });

        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(waitCallback);
    }
}
```

how do i convert such expression to any of its alternative(i.e non lambda code or anonymous methods)?

thanks

Comment: I would suggest taking some time and learn lambdas rather than converting code.

Comment: @Magnus, it won't work in .net 2.0 or will it?

Comment: Do you work with .Net as developer or do the apps have to be deployed there? It's important, because Lambda and any other form of anonymous methods is compiler specific, whilst Linq is .Net 3.5 and up. You can use the 4.0 compiler to target 2.0, which means you can use Lambda's. This piece of code doesn't contain any Linq.

Comment: In this case I would add `wordCopy` and `catCopy` to a Pair object (since tuple does not exists) and use that as the `state` object to the callback function.

Comment: @Dykam i develop targeting .net 2 in some cases either by request, or  mostly to avoid bordering the consumer with slow internet connection with large download. How can i use .net 4 compiler to target .net 2 and still use lambda?

Comment: Go to the project settings by rightclicking on the project -> properties. There is a setting to set the target framework. I think there is one to set the target compiler as well, but that defaults to 4.0. This is only when you use Visual Studio 10.

Comment: @Dykam am using vs2008, i still need to know how to target .n2, but work with .net 4!

Comment: Well, then it is impossible, as the feature of the compiler being able to target multiple frameworks is since VS2010/.Net4.0/C#4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A lambda expression in C# is really just a delegate. Given your using .Net 2.0 you can use anonymous methods to define a delegate on the fly, so replace line of code with:

```
var waitCallback = new WaitCallback(
                        delegate(object state) { 
                             DoSomething(workCopy, catCopy); 
                        });
```

Comment: Of course normally the declared param (state) is used somewhere in the function.

Comment: Although this is not the solution to my problem, i just have to accept an answer anyway

Answer (score 1):

Why are you still using .Net 2? You're missing a lot of great changes, especially LINQ.

That being said, lambdas *are not* a feature of .Net 3.5, they are a feature of C# 3.0 and you can use that while compiling for .Net 2.0, if you really need to do that.

Comment: how can i develop in .net 2 and use lambda, is there any reference?

Comment: @Smith, you have to use Visual Studio that supports it (2008 or 2010) and select target framework in the project properties. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx).